# Damaged PDF file after linearization using qpdf apparently not caused by (La)TeX input

Tags: beamer, pdf

Edit3: I've updated the title, hopefully satisfying the people saying this item is off-topic: The reason I think this post does have value to this community is that the answer maybe off-topic (i.e. a bug in `qpdf`), but the question definitely was not. I spent quite some time fiddling with the Beamer frames that appeared to be the culprit, so let's hope this item can save others the effort.
BTW: I just send a message to Jay on the `qpdf` issue, referring to this post.

I have a PDF document generated using `pdflatex`, and I used `qpdf` to linearize it. The initial document reads and checks fine, while the linearized document has the first pages damaged and produces an error at checking:

```
(object 269 0, file position 307): expected n n obj
```

It's a Beamer presentation including a lot of screengrabs. I thought I found the frame responsible (outcommenting it makes the problem disappear), but the frame looks fine, and even replacing it with a copy of the next frame generates the same problem. And nothing suspicious before it.

Displaying the linearized document using evince gives me a lot of empty pages at the start and errors like this:

```
Syntax Error (4697): No font in show/space
Syntax Error: Unknown font tag 'F21'
```

Any ideas on how to solve this problem or how to debug it?

For those willing to try to linearize themselves: here's the document (warning: 50MB download):

http://www.offerman.com/private_secure_computing/AOC-Private_Secure_Computing-CyanogenMod-nonlin.pdf

(link edited to make room for linearized document)

I also tried `pdfopt`, creating a linearized document that appears to be just fine. Checking it with `qpdf`, however, results in a core dump.

I'm wondering whether it's a problem with qpdf instead of an issue within the document...

Edit: I'm ignoring the `qpdf` core dumping for now; the file generated by `pdfopt` seems to work in Acrobat Reader and Firefox (both on Linux), though Firefox is not showing the document until it has been downloaded completely. Need to look into that.

Edit2: Just checked out the `pdfsizeopt` tool suggested by Keks (tnx!). It requires `sam2p` and `tif22pnm`, for which RPM packages can be found, but also `pngout`, that hasn't been updated for Linux for almost a decade. Looks like a Windows-only party, so I'll leave this for now.

Edit4: applying `pdf2ps` followed by `ps2pdf` does indeed create a smaller PDF document, but it makes me lose all hyperlinks and meta-data. Will report back on `gs`...

Comment: Why do you need qpdf? To shrink the pdf I suggest to use pdfsizeopt.py: https://github.com/pts/pdfsizeopt Great software.

Comment: qpdf was one of the tools for linearization recommended on this site, and I, of course, assumed it was (is?) my document causing the issue instead of qpdf. I don't use anything else than Linux, so consistent behaviour across PDF generators and processors make me feel confident that the document can be read without problems on other platforms.

Comment: Via ghostscript (`pdf2ps` then `ps2pdf`), I got a perfect PDF (14Mb).

Comment: I can confirm this as a bug in qpdf 5.1.1 on Linux. Please report a bug [with the project](http://sourceforge.net/p/qpdf/bugs/). In the past Jay was very responsive.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug in a software not directly related to TeX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @Adrian Regarding your latest edit: See [pdfsizeopt on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/pdfsizeopt/).

Comment: @Adrian : I assume you want to reduce the size of the output pdf file. If so I could recommend you to use this : `gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=file_slim.pdf file.pdf` and especially look at -dPDFSETTINGS to select the one that suits your application (look at http://milan.kupcevic.net/ghostscript-ps-pdf/ for more informations about the options).

Comment: This was indeed a bug in qpdf 5.1.1 (confirmed by the author); it will be fixed in the next release.